# Understanding Maven plugins

Tags: maven

I created a simple maven project.

I want to turn in into a eclipse project.
So I use `mvn eclipse:eclipse`

But I did not specify anything in my POM about eclipse plugin.

When I use another plugins'goal, for example : `mvn jetty:run`

It does not work :

```
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 kB at 59 kB/s)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.302 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-19T09:43:13+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'jetty' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Anthony\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

I don't understand why in the first case (eclipse:eclipse) it works just fine whereas for the other it does not.

However when I add the plugin in my POM it works :

```
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>9.4.12.v20180830</version
```

So yes I don't understand why for eclipse plugin I need nothing whereas for the other one, I need to specidy the plugin in my POM

Thank you

Comment: Do not `eclipse:eclipse` cause the maven-eclipse-plugin has been retired a long time ago. Better import the Maven project via M2E with Eclipse (assuming you are on a recent version of Eclipse)...Furthermore you should simply build your project on command line first...via `mvn clean package`...